# Help Needed Finding a Product Field

Tags: pricebook

Can anyone tell me where I can find the field highlighted in red below please? The related list is for Products, it's just been renamed to Service Line. I've checked in Service Line (Products), Pricebooks &  Opportunity Products with no joy.

If possible, I'd like to rename the field to Solution Offering.

Thanks

[image: Related List for Products/Service Lines]

[image: 2 Different names - Product and Service Line in Layout Editor]

Comment: Have you checked the page layout?

Comment: Hi Mahmood, thanks for you reply. It's very strange. In the Layout there are two different names, Service Line and Product. Neither of which are in the Product Object. See attached image above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Rename Tab names and labels under setup --> customize --> Tab name and labels.
- Search for products and click Edit.
- You should see save and next buttons,click next to be redirected to the screen below.
- See if the product name has been renamed to Service line

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much Rao. That actually explains a lot now, the admin that setup the org renamed a lot of fields/objects within the system.

Comment: most welcome :)